# Rails: Form field not getting passed to method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am doing phone verification of users. I take users to a page where they see their user details and a button to verify phone.

When they click the button, they get a text message with a verification code (this works, done via Twilio) and the model gets updated with the phone_verification_code (this works too). See method "verify" in UsersController.

When the user is on `http://localhost:3000/users/12/verify` page. They see a button to "verify phone", through which I am triggering the "confirm_code" method in the controller.

Two issues here. 1. The form field is pre-populated with the phone_verification_code. I mean for the user to input it manually after getting the text. 2. I am always getting "Could not verify phone at this time" message. It does not appear that I am correctly passing the phone_verification_code to the "confirm_code" method in controller.

What do I need to change?

app/views/users/verify.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => "confirm_code" }  do |f|  %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone_verification_code %>
    <%= f.submit "Verify phone", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
 <%end%>
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :timeoutable

  def confirm_pin(entered_pin)
    update(phone_verified: true) if self.phone_verification_code == entered_pin
  end 

end
```

UserController

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    begin
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      logger.error "Attempt to access an invalid user: #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Attempt to access an invalid user: #{params[:id]}"
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show html.erb
        format.json { render json: @user }
      end
    end
  end

  def verify
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.phone_verification_code = rand(0000..9999).to_s.rjust(4, "0")
    @user.save
    SendTexts.send_verification_code(@user.phone_verification_code)
  end

  def confirm_code
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.confirm_pin(params[:phone_verification_code])
    if @user.phone_verified == true
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Phone number verified"
    else
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Could not verify phone at this time"
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      @user = nil
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params[:user]
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, change the `text_field` like below

```
<%= f.text_field :phone_verification_code, :value => nil %>
```

This avoids the `text_field` pre-populated with the `phone_verification_code`

And for your second issue, the reason why you always get "Could not verify phone at this time" is because you are passing the ***wrong params*** to `confirm_pin` method, so `phone_verified` is ***never set to true***.

***Solution:***

When you look into the `params` that are generated in the log, you will see the `:phone_verification_code` ***inside the user hash***. So change this line `@user.confirm_pin(params[:phone_verification_code])` in `confirm_code` method to `@user.confirm_pin(params[:user][:phone_verification_code])`